# Будет ли данное действие корректным в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Я пишу вот такой код:

```
function setvar(varname) {
var varname = '1';
}
setvar('itemnumber');
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = itemnumber;
```

Будет ли он работать?

Comment: `setvar('itemnumber'); alert(itemnumber);` и смотрим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

нет, var имеет область видимость только внутри функции (глобальная область, если переменная объявлена глобально).

кстати, у вас два раза объявлена переменная varname внутри функции. второе объявление лишнее.

```
function setvar(varname) { //неявный var
    varname = '1'; //здесь var проигнорируется
}
```

чтобы ваш код заработал, функцию нужно написать так:

```
function setvar(varname) {
    window[varname] = '1';
}
setvar('itemnumber');
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = itemnumber; //берется из window
```

Answer (score 2):

Параметры функции имеют область видимости функции. Поэтому если аргумент является одним из примитивных типов, то его изменения внутри функции не будут влиять на сам исходный аргумент.

Поэтому в этом определении функции

```
function setvar(varname) {
var varname = '1';
}
```

исходный аргумент, переданный в качестве значения параметр `varname`, не будет изменен.

Кроме того, вы передаете в функцию строковый литерал, а не переменную, объявленную вне функции

```
setvar('itemnumber');
```

Поэтому данное предложение

```
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = itemnumber;
```

не имеет смысла, так как переменной `itemnumber` не существует.

Вы могли бы создать объект, и его передавать вместе с названием свойства в функцию. Например,

```
function setvar(obj, varname) {
    obj[varname] = '1';
}

var obj = {};

setvar(obj, 'itemnumber');
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = obj.itemnumber;
```